# Can you respond to a UDP packet from a different server?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

If server A receives a UDP packet, can it forward it to server B and have server B directly respond to the end client without going back through server A since UDP is connectionless?

My gut feeling is no, unless both server A and server B have the same IP address (anycast maybe?)

But if the client is built to also be a UDP server, it could work in theory since the (logical) response from server B would just look like a new request. But then this really doesn't work in practice because of firewalls and NAT, for the same reason it's hard to host a game server from behind your firewall, router, and ISP.

Comment: You can send it, but it won't be viewed as a response by the receiver, as it will come from a different source address than the request was sent to, even if firewalls and NAT permit.

Comment: why do you want to do this?  could you set up some (stateful) box near the server that makes sure packets get relayed to the appropriate server?

Comment: Ideally I should be able to forward a request from server A to server B which responds directly to the end user, without having to proxy the potentially large response back through A which doesn't care. It seems the internet really doesn't work that way though, even for connectionless protocols like UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If server A receives a UDP packet, can it forward it to server B and have server B directly respond to the end client without going back through server A since UDP is connectionless?

Yes, it can. However, there are a few caveats:

1. NAT devices, which most client are behind of. There are [several types of NAT devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation). A *full-cone* NAT will accept the redirected packet just fine, but an address-restricted NAT would require the packet to return from the same address it was sent to (hence, your anycast idea would work, as well as simply having server B spoof the IP of server A). A *port restricted* or *symmetric* NAT would also require the same source port (i.e. server B has to send the response from the same port server A received it from).
2. Other types of network [middleboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middlebox), such as firewalls might block the returning packet
3. Application - will the client application accept a response from a different IP address and port?

Comment: Interesting, do you know if that kind of IP spoofing is possible with AWS VPC?

Comment: I think with cloudflare spectrum, which is an anycast UDP reverse proxy, this may be more broadly possible from the "public" cloud - but requires an enterprise account, so I can't test it.

Comment: Never tried spoofing an IP on AWS, but I have a feeling it won't work.